# How to debug nuxt.js "yarn dev" when it just stops loading?

Tags: nuxt.js

Today one of our nuxt.js products just stopped loading when you start it.  There is no error. The browswer never loads.  No log.

What we have tried:

- move to a different port, like 57836 - Same
- Try different branches, rollback to known working state - same problem
- Try a different nuxt porject.  The other project loads fine
- Load the _tailwind view, works find
- Delete the whole project, pull it down again from git and yarn install - Same problem
- run Yarn upgrade, a few things updated, but still the same problem
- Try to load it from a http client like postman, same thing no response
- Try loading in different browsers - same problem

[image]

So my question, how do I even start debugging this? How to I see requests to the build in server?

Comment: Nice debugging already. Try it on another computer/place, maybe it's a firewall (/whatever corpo thing) or something related to your `/etc/hosts`. There is nothing more in another browser (in the console)? Try to create a blank page like `/save-me` with nothing in it and no middleware or alike. Try to build/generate and see if you can preview the result too. Maybe inspect the network tab for some failed requests. Maybe try this [one too](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/configuration#edit-host-and-port) to have an URL like `192.168.1.12` and let a colleague try from his local machine.

Comment: Also, you could maybe try to load the `/save-me` page, with some static content in there but with JS disabled. That way, we'll be able to see if the issue is coming from the client-side.

Comment: It seems like it is related to either docker or VMware, both of which I had running.  Restarting and turning them both off and it will now load.